# Don't allow to click outside dialog

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to see is the user has internet or no.
When the user has no internet, it shows a dialog with a message, but if he touches outside of the dialog, the dialog does nothing.

I've tried with:

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);

dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(!isConnected())
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("No internet")
            .setMessage("Message ")
            .setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int w) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
.show();
        }
    }
    private boolean isConnected()
    {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
}

}
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: what you want to do when user clicks outside of the dialog?

Comment: where did you call dialog.setCancelable(false);?

Comment: do you want to cancel dialog on outside touch?

Comment: I want to disable outside touch, the user needs to click on the "close" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("No internet")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setMessage("Message ")
    .setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int w) {
        finish();
      }
    })
    .show();
```

Comment: Just one more question, it's possible to add this before a splash screen? I've added it, it stays for 2 secods(splash screen time), then disappears.

Comment: You have to start your main activity intent after finish(); in dialog onClick method (if you want to open activity).

Comment: Still closes after 2 seconds :/

Comment: Maybe you start your MainActivity intent outside of dialog OnClick.

Comment: But i can't put the internet code inside the alert dialog?, so, when you open the app, first thing to appear is the dialog

Comment: It doesn't need to put your codes in dialog. Just you need to check internet connection in an if-else block. if(connected) open activity else show dialog. Hope to helps.

Comment: Finally i managed to put it up to work! Thank you for your amazing time that you spent with me! Please keep helping "non-experience" guys like me ;D Thanks for real!

Comment: np buddy :) @GuiSousa

Comment: you can accept the answer @GuiSousa